# Queuing up blog posts from offline

Tags: scheduled-tasks, blogging, queue

I have a Blogger blog and I will be going for long periods of time when I can only access the web via dial-up for short periods in the middle of the night (much like the so-called "flash sessions" that were common in the early days of AOL).

I'm looking for a system of creating blog posts while offline and queuing them up to be published during the night. If I can get this, I'll be happy, but there is one more thing I'm also looking for. I would like to set a delay for each post of about a week.

Anybody got a silver bullet for me?

Comment: Blog via email ? http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41452

Comment: @Sathya, why is this not a real answer so I can vote for it?

Comment: posted as an answer @CarlF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out [Windows Live Writer](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer) lets me work offline and upload en masse as well as post-date my blog posts. Worked out great!

Answer (score 1):

You could also blog by email

> The Mail-to-Blogger feature turns any email account into a blog-posting application. In Settings | Email you can create a Mail-to-Blogger address which you will use to send posts via email to your blog:

have a look at this [blogger help article](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41452) for more details.

Comment: I don't like it because I can't schedule my posts to appear at a specified date other than that of the email.

Comment: well you _could_ have it saved as a draft and post it as required. @Keyslinger